# Sql Server query from java/hibernate randomly times out when called within a loop

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, t-sql, sqljdbc

I encounter a weird problem while trying to perform a sql query from a java call to sqlserver.

A single call to the java function goes well, but when I do the same within a loop (from 2 to 30 iterations), I sometimes (not always) got such an error :

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Le délai imparti à la requête a expiré.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.checkForInterrupt(IOBuffer.java:5918)

**The few things I noticed :**

- It always fail at the same step of the loop, provided the iterated item remain unchanged (eg, if it fails at step 7 of 15, it will always fail at step 7!)
- It will fail at another step if I skip or change any iterated item, including the previously failing one... and it does not fail at the next step, but - what looks like - at a random one
- If I copy/paste the failing query (from debugging) into SqlQueryBrowser and execute it : it works
- If I copy/paste the failing query from Sql Server Profiler : it works!
- If I execute the loop from within sql server query browser (iterating over input parameters) : it works!
- If I execute the loop from within a JUnit Test, only iterating over the paremeters : it also works!!
- From Sql Server Profiler, I can see the successfull requests take 200 to 600 ms to complete when the failing one takes exactly 15000 ms ( = currently configured timeout)
- When I change the timeout, the query keeps timing out.

**This is what I tried to perform, with no success :**

- Use one transaction per step / query
- Update server 'connect timeout' et 'query timeout' through sp_[serveroption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-serveroption-transact-sql) (*EXEC sp_serveroption 'myServer\SQLEXPRESS', 'connect timeout', 45;*)
- Change *queryTimeout* from java
- Change "query wait" option from Sql Query Browser {Server} > "properties" > "advanced" > "parallelism"
- Do not drop the temporary table #MATCHINGDAYS
- Add a random token to #MATCHINGDAYS to prevent concurrency conflicts
- Add BEGIN / END around the query
- Delay the request with [WAITFOR DELAY t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql)
- use a stored procedure instead of a string holding the request
- perform a flush + clear of the session from within the "finally" statement.
- Restart of the SqlServer + tomcat
- Update driver to mssql-jdbc 6.1.0.jre7
- Use an actual table instead of a temporary one

**the java call**

(*It is embedded in a single transaction*)

```
final SessionImpl sess = (SessionImpl) this.getSessionFactory().openSession();
try (Connection conn = sess.connection(); Statement st = conn.createStatement();) {
    final NamedParameterPreparedStatement ps = NamedParameterPreparedStatement.createNamedParameterPreparedStatement(conn, aStringWithTheRequestBelow);
        // ... set parameters here ...
    ps.setQueryTimeout(15);
    final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
} catch (final SQLException ex) {
    LOG.error("parameter 1 :" + parameter1 + "etc.");
} finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

**the TSQL query**

*(I made it brain-and-eyes-friendly, but it is a little more tricky that what it looks like; but basicely, you have the idea of it)*

```
--DECLARE @date as DATE = '2017-09-03'; -- one of the input parameter set up from java.


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MATCHINGDAYS718567154','U') is not null 
DROP TABLE #MATCHINGDAYS718567154; -- RANDOM TOKEN HERE TO AVOID CONCURRENCY

WITH startDateTable AS ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 a.dateStart 
    FROM   someSelection
), 
endDateTable AS ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 endDate
    FROM   anotherSelection
), 
AllDays  AS ( 
    SELECT myFunc_getMaxDate(DATEADD(DAY,1,startDateTable.dateStart), DATEADD(dd, -30,@date))AS [Date] 
    FROM startDateTable 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT    
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) 
    from  AllDays 
    join endDateTable on 1=1 
     WHERE    [Date] < myFunc_getMinDate(DATEADD(dd, +7, @date),endDateTable.endDate)) 


-- build a temporary table with all days from startDate to endDate the recursive way
-- with a min -30 days before input date and 7 days after output date    
SELECT [Date] 
     INTO #MATCHINGDAYS718567154 
         FROM    AllDays 
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 37) 

SELECT   
    manyFields

from MainTable
-- various joins
join #MATCHINGDAYS718567154 as MD on 1 = 1 
where 1 = 1
and -- etc... many clauses including some computed over MATCHINGDAYS718567154

order by someField

DROP TABLE #MATCHINGDAYS718567154
```

**Some other info**

- java 1.7_071
- hibernate 4.3.4.Final
- SqlServer Express 2014
- Tomcat 7
- sqljdbc4 4.0

**Edit 28/11 : THE CAUSE**

somewhere in my loop, an object from the same table of the the queried item is inserted from time to time. It is performed in a separated transaction (though I also tried to perform it in the same transaction). The problem does not occur on the iteration when the object is inserted, but in the following iteration... Now, I have the cause... I still do not understand why this causes a failure on the next iteration... Though I suspect it will be perfectly obvious once I will understand it!

```
someIterationOver(List<SomeObject> manyObjects){
    from(SomeObject mo : manyObjects){
        List<MyTableObject> myTableObjects = performMyBigQueryOver(mo.getSomeId());
        for(MyTableObject myTableSingleObject : myTableObjects){
            if(myTableSingleObject.matchesSomeCondition()){
                TableSingleObject aNewTableSingleObject = new TableSingleObject("newTableObject");
                // this will cause the problem in the next iteration
                saveTableObject(aNewTableSingleObject);
            }
        }

    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void saveTableObject(ableSingleObject aNewTableSingleObject){
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.save(aNewTableSingleObject); // works fine
}
```

... any tips are welcome here!

Comment: Plenty of possible problems: 1. Query runs slows and sometimes, dependigs on parameter value it timeouts. 2. Async calls are building up and a loop iteraction is called while the query don't finished  answering previous iteration. 3 Session factory not working properly. 3. Too many iterations 18k iterations in that loop with 200ms each menas 1 hour query runing. Keep in mind 200ms is not a good time for an query and maybe you can cut off that loop and fetch all the records you do need only changing the query to get all in one go

Comment: Jean, thanks for your comment. 1 since this is not related to a specific input parameter, and since the query itself (out of the loop) works fine, this does not sound the pb. 2 I agree, but the call here is synchronous. 3 SessionFactory has been working fine for 5 years (updated from time to time).. I don't understand what could be wrong here regarding it... I think any pb should have been detected by nom (do you have hint here ?) 4 I forgot to state the number of iterations here : it goes from 2 to 30.... far from 18k!

Comment: Relative to 1 it remembered once when a loop was calling a query passing a costumer ID in each iteration to get his orderds. on specific costumer id was causing a time out. 2. Try to change connection timeout and see if it helps to find out the culprint. if only a few iterations I can put a break point and test each query call

Comment: Yes, I did try both : changing query timeout (which is reached whatever the timeout is) and put a breakpoint, in order to test the failing query or dig into the Session object : no success!

Comment: Theres something smelling here. If you can run it in the same server/base using the same connection/user the problem is not the query per se but timeout means clearly a call for the DB is taking to much time to complete. Maybe it's somekind of lock or something in your test is nor right. There's only a longshot I can try, use a table variable instead of a temp table to be sure there's not a problem with it between calls

Comment: If nothing more works consider the very, very rare case of a driver bug. it happened before http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7105007  be sure youa re using a updated drive (or bug started after an update)

Comment: I have tried to update the driver, with no success. About the table variable, I followed your advice and tried to use a previously-created... but is keeps failing, again and again!

Comment: I see you are trying hard to get ride of this bug. Well there's little left. Can be a permission/connection problem but try to run a single query OUT of the loop. I want to rule out the prolem is inside the loop since I guess all other queries(login included) in  your system works. And be sure your app is connecting hititng the same DB where you are (out of the app) testing the query and be sure they are the very same query (use a profiler)

Comment: And I see you are trying hard to help as well : thanks! About the query outside the loop : works fine. And also : I eventually managed to find the line causing the pb (that was not where I was looking). I edited my post to show the cause... I am still looking for the fix

Comment: That explains a lot. For sure a lock problem. Be sure the insertion is commited before the query runs. Also if things are in parallel one can block the other, timeout are very common in those conditions. You can test that (and dependent tables) for locks before the select to be sure and throw an exception SQL side. Note indexing have a impact on granularity of locks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to have it work : moving the "saveTableObject" method from within the loop to outside of it did the trick...
But although I found a solution, I still do not understand why a previous insert, embedded in its own devoted transaction, caused this lock to be maintained to the next iteration and in another transaction!... So if you have tips : they are still welcome!

By the way, this [post](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p694/sp_wholock-a-t-sql-stored-proc-combining-sp_who-and-sp_lock-to-show-whos-locking-what-and-how-much#gsc.tab=0) helped me a lot to find out which object was locked!

@Jean : thanks a lot for your many questions that helped me focus on the core cause!